# How do I grant elevated privileges for a program during runtime?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, uac, runtime

When I've already started an application with a normal user account, at some point I may face that the program actually requires an elevated privilege for some operation.

Closing and restarting the program, depending on its design and the operation state, is not always convenient and in some situations it could mean data loss.

Is there a way to grant elevated privileges for an already running program (one that does not have a self-elevating feature built-in) during its run time?

**edit** note that my user is an Administrator.

Comment: More simple : i will make the program always run with admin privileges. For that, `right-click on the exe file -> Properties -> Compatibility tab -> Check "run this program as an admin"`. Does it seems suitable for you ?

Comment: @techie007 yes it is a duplicate. sorry i made a search but didnt find it

Comment: @naxa No problems. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to elevate a program that started un-elevated. The security token the program has is set at program start and can not change. Programs that "appear" to change while running are either starting a hidden background process to do the work or restarting the main process and picking up where the un-elevated one left off.

If you want to always want to run the program elevated you can do like it was said in the comments

> right-click on the exe file -> Properties -> Compatibility tab -> Check "run this program as an admin"